# How to insert multiple rows at once in MySQL DB using Struts2?

Tags: javascript, java, mysql, jsp, struts2

I am trying to insert multiple rows (dynamic rows-retrieved from DB) at once in MySQL DB using Struts2.
For this, firstly I am retrieving data in an HTML table from a DB table (and the rows are dynamic means it depends on how many entries were their in DB for a particular user id).
In my HTML table, there are six columns from which five are retrieved from DB and the last column entries, user has to fill.

Now I wants to insert this whole data (as many rows as retrieved from the DB with the new entries of last column) to another table of DB at once.
Right now I am able to insert whole data but it is not getting stored in separate rows in DB table, it is just stored in a single row with comma separated.

Any help would be appreciated...Thanks in advance!!

Comment: you should add your code.

Comment: html and java code please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your help people...i found the solution!!
Before sending data to DB, i split each entry of data for particular rows..and it's working!!! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try for executing Records in batch [Read Here](http://tutorialspointexamples.com/jdbc-callablestatement-stored-procedure-batch-update-example/)
Change `execute` as passing list

```
public String execute() throws Exception 
{
    String ret = "SUCCESS";
    try
    {
        msg = db.Detailsdb.addMoreDetails(details);
        if(msg != null)
        {
            System.out.println(msg);
            return ret;
        }
        else 
            ret = "ERROR";
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Change your DB logic for adding Batches

```
public static  String addMoreDetails(List<Details> details) throws Exception
{  
    try
    {
     java.sql.CallableStatement cs = connect().prepareCall("{call addUpdMoreDetails(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)}");
     for(Details det : details) {
         cs.setString(1, "I");
         cs.setString(2, det.detailsId);
         cs.setString(3, det.userId);
         cs.setString(4, det.info_1);
         cs.setString(5, det.info_2);
         cs.setString(6, det.info_3);
         cs.setString(7, det.info_4);
         cs.setString(8, det.info_5);
         cs.registerOutParameter(9, Types.VARCHAR);
         cs.addBatch();
    }
    int counts[] = cs.executeBatch();
    if ( counts.length == details.size )
        return "someMEssage";
    else
        return null; 
   }
   catch(Exception ex)
   {
    return ex.toString();
   }
}
```

Comment: hey shantaram...thnks for replying!! but it's not helpful in what i needed. I tried your code with minor changes like i'm using "det.getDetailsId" instead of "det.detailsId" and i replaced "details.size" with "details.size()".
first it gives me "java.sql.SQLException: Can't call executeBatch() on CallableStatement with OUTPUT parameters" message while executing, after that i remove out parameter from my code and passing only 8 parametrs than it's giving me "java.sql.SQLException: boo!" message.

Comment: just now i made some changes in my procedure, i passed only 7 parameters their (also removed 'I' for insertion (from both procedure and java class)) and now it's inserting data but in the same way as earlier.
No improvements yet..!! :(

Comment: provide your Stored Procedure `addUpdMoreDetails`